# Assign ID column based on multiple columns

Tags: r, duplicates, conditional-statements, identity, assign

**The question below is solved here:**  [Create ID variable: if ≥1 column duplicate then mark as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71486038/create-id-variable-if-%e2%89%a51-column-duplicate-then-mark-as-duplicate)
**and here:**
[assign ID based on duplicate integer variable and logical variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71468682/assign-id-based-on-duplicate-integer-variable-and-logical-variable)

I would like to create a new column with an ID code based on multiple conditions of several columns.
This is a sample of my data.

```
     pat     N     C    NC n1    c1   
 1     1     1     1     1 FALSE FALSE
 2     2     1     1     1 FALSE FALSE
 3     3    12    31     2 FALSE FALSE
 4     4    12    31     2 FALSE FALSE
 5     5     3    15     3 FALSE TRUE 
 6     6     4    15     4 FALSE TRUE 
 7     7     5    18     5 TRUE  FALSE
 8     8     5    20     6 TRUE  FALSE
 9     9     6    21     7 FALSE FALSE
10    10     7    21     8 FALSE FALSE
11    11     8    19     9 FALSE FALSE
12    12     9    11    10 FALSE FALSE
13    13    10    11    11 FALSE FALSE
14    14    11    14    12 FALSE FALSE

sample <- data.frame(pat = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14), 
                      N = c(1,1,12,12,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,11), 
                     C = c(1,1,31,31,15,15,18,20,21,21,19,11,11,14),
                     NC = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
                     n1 = c("FALSE", "FALSE","FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE", "FALSE","FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE"),
                     c1 = c("FALSE", "FALSE","FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE", "FALSE","FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE"))
```

EDIT:
With some help i've now managed to create new ID columns for these 2 conditions ([assign ID based on duplicate integer variable and logical variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71468682/assign-id-based-on-duplicate-integer-variable-and-logical-variable/71469953#71469953))

2. column N is duplicate and column n1 is FALSE, or
3. column C is duplicate and column c1 is FALSE.

The dataframe now looks like this:

```
     pat     N     C    NC n1    c1        new_ID_N   new_ID_C
 1     1     1     1     1 FALSE FALSE     1           1
 2     2     1     1     1 FALSE FALSE     1           1
 3     3    12    31     2 FALSE FALSE     2           2
 4     4    12    31     2 FALSE FALSE     2           2
 5     5     3    15     3 FALSE TRUE      3           3
 6     6     4    15     4 FALSE TRUE      4           4
 7     7     5    18     5 TRUE  FALSE     5           5
 8     8     5    20     6 TRUE  FALSE     6           6
 9     9     6    21     7 FALSE FALSE     7           7
10    10     7    21     8 FALSE FALSE     8           7
11    11     8    19     9 FALSE FALSE     9           8
12    12     9    11    10 FALSE FALSE     10          9
13    13    10    11    11 FALSE FALSE     11          9
14    14    11    14    12 FALSE FALSE     12          10
```

Finally i would like to create the last new_ID column with numbers, but marked as a duplicate number if:

1. column NC is duplicate, OR
2. new_ID_N is duplicate, OR
3. new_ID_C is duplicate.

I've tried the script suggested in the answers

```
sample <- data.table::as.data.table(sample)[
  j = new_ID := base::as.numeric(base::interaction(var1, var..., varn,
                                                   drop=TRUE))
]
```

But this shows an error message '(cannot allocate vector of size ..., in addtion warning message: In ans lenght(l): NAs produced by integer overflow).

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This code makes it possible to create an unique ID based on multiple variables.

```
sample <- data.table::as.data.table(sample)[
  j = new_ID := base::as.numeric(base::interaction(var1, var..., varn,
                                                   drop=TRUE))
]
```

Since your explanation is not really clear to me, I let you try this by yourself. I believe you have to create a new variable/column for each condition, then put those variables into the code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you suggest i first create two new column with ID number based on condition (N=duplicates & n1=False -> column 'newN') and (C=duplicate & c1= false-> column 'newC'). And then create the column new_ID based if NC=duplicate or 'newN'=duplicate or newC=duplicate?

Comment: I've edited the question. I think i now did what you suggested (create a new variable/column) for each condition. But when i put these in your code i get an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option:

```
sample <- data.frame(pat = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14), 
                      N = c(1,1,12,12,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,11), 
                     C = c(1,1,31,31,15,15,18,20,21,21,19,11,11,14),
                     NC = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
                     n1 = c(FALSE, FALSE,FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE, FALSE,FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
                     c1 = c(FALSE, FALSE,FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE, FALSE,FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))


sample <- sample[order(sample$NC, sample$N, sample$C), ]

id <- 1
sample[1, 'new_ID'] <- id

for (i in 2:nrow(sample)) {

  if (((sample[i, 'NC'] != sample[i - 1, 'NC']) | sample[i - 1, 'n1']) &
      ((sample[i, 'C'] != sample[i - 1, 'C']) | sample[i - 1, 'c1'])) {
    id <- id + 1
  }

  sample[i, 'new_ID'] <- id

}
```

```
> sample
   pat  N  C NC    n1    c1 new_ID
1    1  1  1  1 FALSE FALSE      1
2    2  1  1  1 FALSE FALSE      1
3    3 12 31  2 FALSE FALSE      2
4    4 12 31  2 FALSE FALSE      2
5    5  3 15  3 FALSE  TRUE      3
6    6  4 15  4 FALSE  TRUE      4
7    7  5 18  5  TRUE FALSE      5
8    8  5 20  6  TRUE FALSE      6
9    9  6 21  7 FALSE FALSE      7
10  10  7 21  8 FALSE FALSE      7
11  11  8 19  9 FALSE FALSE      8
12  12  9 11 10 FALSE FALSE      9
13  13 10 11 11 FALSE FALSE      9
14  14 11 14 12 FALSE FALSE     10
```

If it weren't for the `n1`/`c1` constraints, you should be able to use `as.integer(factor(...)` where `...` = a `paste` or `interaction` call with the variables needed.

But with `n1` and `c1`, all I could think of was a loop. This requires sorting first! And note that you had quotes around `TRUE` and `FALSE`, which I removed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, when i run this script i get an error: 
Error in if (((sample[i, "NC"] != sample[i - 1, "NC"]) |  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.
In my complete dataset there are some rows that have NA for column N or C or NC. The columns n1 and c1 dont have NA values. Might this be the reason for the error?

Comment: Yes, that is probably the reason. What behavior do you want when you have NA in these columns?

Comment: I've replaced all NA values for a number. A NA value meant that a ID code was missing prior, if i change it to a number i can later check the new_ID number and change it back to NA i think.
Now the script doesn't give any errors. However i see that the new_ID column only gives duplicate number ID's to column NC duplicates and not for (column N duplicate + n1=False) and (column C duplicate + c1=False). But when i run your code on the sample it works perfectly, im not sure what im doing wrong here...

Comment: Did you sort your data frame first? That is required. If so, hmm, I am not sure. Might be an error in my conditional expression but I don't see anything obvious. Share a reproducible example if you are able.

Comment: Yes i sorted the df first by using: sample[order(sample$NC, sample$N, sample$C), ]. It's difficult to share a reproducible code for my dataset, because its very large (>490.00 rows). the only thing that is different is the column and dataframe names.

sample=assign_DD, N=Dup_N, C=Dup_C, NC=Dup_NC, n1=overlap, c1=overlapC. But ive adjusted the names in your script, so im unsure if thats the problem