# Create ID variable: if ≥1 column duplicate then mark as duplicate

Tags: r, duplicates, conditional-statements, assign

Ive seen many questions about creating a new ID variable, based on multiple columns conditions. However it is usually if var1 AND var2 are double, then mark as duplicate number.

My question is how do you create a new variable ID and mark for duplicates if

1. var1 is duplicate, OR
2. var2 is duplicate, OR
3. var3 is duplicate.

Example dataset **(EDITED)**:

```
      pat         var1   var2       var3     
 1     1          1      10           1       
 2     2          16     10          11       
 3     3          21     27           2       
 4     4          22     29           2       
 5     5          31     35           3       
 6     6          44     47           4       
 7     7          5      50           5       
 8     8          6      60           6       
 9     9          7      70           7       
10    10          8      80           7       
11    11          9      90           8       
12    12         10      11           9       
13    13         11      13           91      
14    14         11      14           10     
15    15         NA      15           15
16    16         NA      15           16
17    17         12      NA           17
18    18         13      NA           18

 sample <- data.frame(pat = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18), 
                     var1 = c(1,16,21,22,31,44,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,11, NA,NA,12,13), 
var2 = c(10,10,27,29,35,47,50,60,70,80,90,11,13,14,15,15,NA,NA),
                     var3 = c(1,11,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,91,10,15,16,17,18)
```

So if one of the three var variables is duplicated, then the new ID variable should show a duplicate ID number.

Desired output **(EDITED)**:

```
      pat         var1   var2       var3     ID
 1     1          1      10           1       1
 2     2          16     10          11       1
 3     3          21     27           2       2
 4     4          22     29           2       2
 5     5          31     35           3       3
 6     6          44     47           4       4
 7     7          5      50           5       5
 8     8          6      60           6       6
 9     9          7      70           7       7
10    10          8      80           7       7
11    11          9      90           8       8
12    12         10      11           9       9
13    13         11      13           91      10
14    14         11      14           10      10
15    15         NA      15           15      11
16    16         NA      15           16      11
17    17         12      NA           17      12
18    18         13      NA           18      13
```

I couldnt find a question based on similar conditions therefor im asking it.
Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT** The answer of Ben works perfect if there are no NA values present. Unfortunately I did not mention I also had NA values present in for var1,2 or 3.  A NA value meant that idnumber for Var1/2/3 was missing. So ive adjusted the question a bit and added some NA values.
The added question is:

Is it possible for a script to judge: if var1=c(NA,NA), var2=(1,1) and var3=(1,2) to report a duplicate but if var1=c(NA,NA), var2=c(1,2) and var3=(1,2) to report a unique number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try the following. Here we use `tail` and `head` to refer to rows 2 through 14 compared to 1 through 13 (effectively comparing each row with the prior row).

We can use `rowSums` of differences between each row and the previous row. If the difference is zero, then the result is `TRUE` (or 1), and the `ID` would increase for each value of 1 from row to row. These are cumulatively summed with `cumsum`.

The use of `c` will make the first `ID` 1. Also, the `cumsum` is adjusted by 1 to account for the initial `ID` of 1.

```
sample$ID <- 
  c(1, cumsum(rowSums(tail(sample[-1], -1) == head(sample[-1], -1)) == 0) + 1)

sample
```

**Output**

```
   pat var1 var2 var3 ID
1    1    1   10    1  1
2    2   16   10   11  1
3    3   21   27    2  2
4    4   22   29    2  2
5    5   31   35    3  3
6    6   44   47    4  4
7    7    5   50    5  5
8    8    6   60    6  6
9    9    7   70    7  7
10  10    8   80    7  7
11  11    9   90    8  8
12  12   10   11    9  9
13  13   11   13   91 10
14  14   11   14   10 10
```

---

**Edit**: Based on comment below, there are occasions where the value is `NA` which should be ignored. In the example above, `NA` repeated (such as `var2` in rows 17-18) does not count as a duplicate.

Here is another approach. You can use `sapply` to go through the rows numbers of your data.frame.

You can use `mapply` to subtract each var from the row next to a given row, and check if `any` have a value of zero. Note that `na.rm = T` will ignore missing `NA` values.

```
sample$ID <-
  c(1,
    cumsum(
      sapply(
        seq_len(nrow(sample)-1),
        \(x) {
          !any(mapply(`-`, sample[x, -1, drop = T], sample[x + 1, -1, drop = T]) == 0, na.rm = T)
        }
      )
    ) + 1
  )
```

**Output**

```
   pat var1 var2 var3 ID
1    1    1   10    1  1
2    2   16   10   11  1
3    3   21   27    2  2
4    4   22   29    2  2
5    5   31   35    3  3
6    6   44   47    4  4
7    7    5   50    5  5
8    8    6   60    6  6
9    9    7   70    7  7
10  10    8   80    7  7
11  11    9   90    8  8
12  12   10   11    9  9
13  13   11   13   91 10
14  14   11   14   10 10
15  15   NA   15   15 11
16  16   NA   15   16 11
17  17   12   NA   17 12
18  18   13   NA   18 13
```

Comment: Thank you Ben! This script works when there are no NA values. 
However, i also have several NA values in each column (stupid of me not to mention this!) this makes it a bit more difficult. A NA value meant that idnumber for Var1/2/3 was missing. Is it possible for a script to judge: if var1=c(NA,NA), var2=(1,1) and var3=(1,2) to report a duplicate but if var1=c(NA,NA), var2=c(1,2) and var3=(1,2) to report a unique number?
Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: @RvS See edited answer - let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @ Ben. Thanks for you answer. When i run this code i get an error: "unexpected input in: seq_len(nrow(sample)-1), \" And then after the !any function is shows an error: object X not found.  I've tried changing \ to / (ive had troubles with this before) but this doesnt solve the errors.

Comment: @RvS Oh - sorry - replace `\(x)` with `function(x)` - the shorthand for `function` requires R version 4.1.0+